# Can't create invoice details with manual discount using OrganizationServiceClient in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, invoice

I'm using `OrganizationServiceClient` with `CRM 2011`, When I create an `invoicedetail` with a `manualdiscountamount`, the discount doesn't appear in the `CRM website`.
Here's my code:

```
OrganizationServiceClient client = new OrganizationServiceClient("CustomBinding_IOrganizationService",new EndpointAddress(AuthenticationInfo.OrganizationServiceUrl))) {                client.ConfigureCrmOnlineBinding(AuthenticationInfo.OrganizationPolicy.IssuerUri);
client.Token = AuthenticationInfo.OrganizationToken;

Entity entityDetails =  = new Entity();
entityDetails.LogicalName = "invoicedetail";
entityDetails.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "productid",
                                value =
                                    new EntityReference() {
                                        LogicalName = "product",
                                        Id = Guid.Parse("Some Product Id")
                                    }
                            });
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "uomid",
                                value =
                                    new EntityReference() {
                                        LogicalName = "uom",
                                        Id = Guid.Parse("33B75DB8-8771-4B5A-875F-810CC0732C0C")
                                    }
                            });
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "invoiceid",
                                value = new EntityReference() {LogicalName = "invoice", Id = Guid.Parse("Some Invoice Id")}
                            });
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "quantity",
                                value = 1
                            });
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "createdon",
                                value = DateTime.Now
                            });
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "manualdiscountamount",
                                value = 15
                            });

invoiceDetailsId = client.Create(entityDetails);
```

What may be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use following code to add manualdiscountamount field:

```
entityDetails.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePairOfstringanyType() {
                                key = "manualdiscountamount",
                                value = new Money(Convert.ToDecimal(15))
                            });
```

Because manualdiscountamount field is of Money type. Recheck following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334735.aspx)